# How to set gas price to zero?

Tags: metamask, gas-price, nethermind

I set Nethermind to zero gas price:

```json
    "Blocks": {
        "MinGasPrice": 0
    },
```

Nevertheless, MetaMask for this network shows rather big positive gas prices and does not allow to set the gas price to 0 (or about zero).

Why can't I set the gas price in MetaMask to zero? Is it possible to implement private network with zero gas price and use MetaMask without gas?

Once (apparently, as a result of a MetaMask bug) the gas price were set to zero. Then the transaction didn't validate.